# Oracle 12c - SQL Loader Invalid month Error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-loader

I'm getting ORA-01843: not a valid month error while loading the data using tab delimited text file with sql loader 11.1.0.6.0  on oracle 12c.

control file:

```
options (skip=1)
load data
truncate
into table test_table
fields terminated by '\t' TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
  type,
  rvw_date "case when :rvw_date = 'NULL' then null  WHEN       REGEXP_LIKE(:rvw_date, '\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}') THEN to_date(:rvw_date,'yyyy/mm/dd')   else to_date(:rvw_date,'mm-dd-yy') end"
)
```

Data:

```
type     rvw_date
Phone    2014/01/29
Phone    2014/02/13
Field    NULL
Phone    01/26/15
Field    02/25/12
```

Schema:

```
create table test_table
(
    type varchar2(20),
    rvw_date date
)
```

Comment: Why have you specified `mm-dd-yyyy` when you're looking for `yyyy/mm/dd`?

Comment: i was testing with yyyy/mm/dd itself but later I changed to mm-dd-yyyy to see whether it works. I have edited the question. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL*Loader control file is [interpreting a backslash as an escape character](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-0BAFDC4F-A289-4E0D-BA4B-59C1757F3D38.htm), it seems. The [SQL operator section](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-83FF6EDC-C7F8-4F29-8994-59153BE31924.htm#SUTIL1226) shows double-quotes being escaped too; it ins't obvious it would apply to anything else, but it kind of makes sense that a single backslash would always be assumed to be escaping something.

Your regular expression pattern needs to double-escape the `\d` to make the pattern work in the file as it does in plain SQL. At the moment the pattern is not matched, so all the values to go the `else`, which is the wrng format mask (even when they are both corrected).

This works:

```
options (skip=1)
load data
truncate
into table test_table
fields terminated by '\t' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  type,
  rvw_date "case when :rvw_date = 'NULL' then null when REGEXP_LIKE(:rvw_date,'\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}') then to_date(:rvw_date,'yyyy/mm/dd') else to_date(:rvw_date,'mm/dd/rr') end"
)
```

With your original data that creates rows:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
select * from test_table;

TYPE                 RVW_DATE  
-------------------- ----------
Phone                2014-01-29
Phone                2014-02-13
Field                          
Phone                2015-01-26
Field                2012-02-25
```